Worried in regards to an email i sent my manager raising concers about training amd colleague health
TL/DR: I got put into a situation in which I did not feel adequately trained, and my colleague has been under extreme pressure and has started having breakdowns at work because none of the managers are listening to her or offering help.
I emailed my boss raising my concerns and he replied very defensively and told me I have no right to message about my colleague or the training. I told him I was simply voicing my concerns and it is unprofessional to say I have no right as I was worried for her health and I had her permission to send the email.
I'm scared of what will happen now and don't know what to do.
So basically the situation I am in just now is:
I am fairly new to my job role and I recently got put under a lot of pressure I wasn't ready for. I managed to get everything sorted out just fine but it was a very difficult period.
At the same time a colleague of mine has been under very very intense pressure and she handles over double of the client meetings and arrangements any other staffer does. She does this because she really wants to progress through the company as she loves her job and has been there since she was 18. Recently her dream job opened up in the company so she applied for it.
After hearing nothing back about it she emailed her managed. He never responded, so next time he was in her branch she asked him in person and was told they need her in the role she is in now so basically they aren't considering her for the job.
I have now been placed in her branch to try and help and she had a breakdown the other day and the workload for 1 person is insane.
I decided to send an email to our regional manager to bring some of my concerns to his attention. I said:
I believe we should have more training in preparing new starters for the extremely busy branches before someone is put in by themselves and while I did get all of the work done it could lead to issues in the future. It could be something to consider for the next set of new starters and it would be beneficial to staff and the company.
I also said:
I am worried about (colleague) as she has more workload than other staff members and I can see the stress and pressure is getting to her. She puts a lot into the company and it hurts to see how she is struggling. I ask you to consider getting more support up to this branch as I think it could really help her out.
The email I got back was disheartening
he had said:
The personal development after initial training is on the staff member and the only issues are with me. If I can't handle the volume of work it's my fault (I had only said it was something to try and implement for the next set of new starts).
In regards to the comments about my colleague he said:
The issue is none of my concern and I shouldn't be emailing him with any of this and I have no right to try and speak for her (note. I had asked her before if she was okay with me sending the initial email and she was and thanked me for trying to stand up for her).
I replied today and pointed out I was only raising the issue on training as a concern. I suggested what could be done to help with this in the future and said I think there may have been some confusion on the purpose of my message. I didn't want to complain to him, I wanted to let him know of my concerns of the matter and bring it to his attention.
I said I believe I have every right to speak about my colleague as I am very worried about her health and wellbeing because of this stress and I was hoping he could do something to assist her. I told him I thought his reply was unprofessional in regard to my colleague because I should be able to bring this to a managers attention and I was only trying to help her out.
A bunch of my colleagues have now been making jokes about me going to get sacked and "it was nice knowing you".
The manager hasn't replied yet but I am now worried and not sure what I should do.
I love my job I just wanted to try and help my colleague and raise an issue with my manager.
Have I done anything wrong or have I done the right thing? I'm really not sure at this point.

If you do anything, it should probably be to apologize for your rudeness. There are ways to try to address this sort of thing; your response was not one of them.

Do you and this coworker share the same manager ? Why doesn't your coworker speak up for herself ? Has your coworker ever talk to her manager about her busy schedule, stress, and pressure, which cause her health issues ?

Never tell your manager they are being unprofessional. That is a career-limiting action.
What you do now is apologise for being rude and promise not to do that again.
Then, if the apology is accepted and you are sure you are forgiven, you can say "I know I overreacted, but it does seem that J is overstressed and close to burn-out. Can you help me figure out how best to support her, and how to organize the work better?"

"Never" seems a little absolute, I'm sure there are good reasons when one choses truth over a "career" under an individual perceived as unprofessional. But yeah, one should be aware of the consequences.

There are better ways to tell them they are doing something inappropriate.

You are newish at this job and have started criticizing your manager. I think that is foolhardy and career limiting.
You are new at the job, so you need to toe the line and, keep your head down. Or be an activist and don't worry about your job. You can't appoint yourself into a union rep position.
Email is absolutely the worst way to do this. It's impersonal, and you can't soften your words.
A better way to do this would have been to approach your manager, apologise for interrupting, say you would like to discuss something when he has some time. Then start to say that you are worried about your colleague's health. Don't present your conclusions. Engage in a conversation. And hint at the issues. For instance ask him if something could be done and gently lead the conversation.
